# Azure Active Directory - No Valid Subscription Found

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a Database configured to use Integrated Auth.  In other words, I have an App Service, and I want it to use Integrated Auth so that I don't have to use Sql Server username/password in a connection string.

So I went to my existing Azure Account and created an Azure Active Directory.

The Active Directory was created, and I then switched to this Directory.  However, all of the resources of my usual Azure account are not to be found.  It is as if I had created a brand new Azure account.

If I try to create a resource, it tells me that I have no subscription, and that I need to create one. So I created one, but it ended up getting linked to my original account, not the new Active Directory Account.

I tried again to add a subscription, but it asks me to sign in, but I don't understand how I am supposed to sign in to the new AD account.

I am not understanding what is going on here.  Is an Azure Active Directory a new and different account than my original?

How do I "sign in" to the new active directory so I can add a subscription?

Answer (score 0):

An Azure subscription is always linked to an Azure AD tenant (directory).

The hierarchy looks like this:

- Your default Azure AD

  - Subscription

    - SQL DB
- The new Azure AD you created

So you can see the SQL DB is looking at the Azure AD you already had.
Because that's the one linked to the sub where the DB is.
Make sure you are looking at the directory where your DB is, you should be able to go to "Azure Active Directory" from the service list.

"Integrated auth" usually means AD authentication, so I want to clarify that Azure SQL does not support that.
Neither does App Service.
What they do support is Azure AD authentication, which is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication.
Mostly I recommend enabling a Managed Identity on the App Service, granting it access to the database, and then using that from within the app to connect.